# C - Dynamic Memory Allocation

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>

int main()
{
    char *string1;
    int length;

    scanf("%d", &length);

    string1 = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * length);


    printf("\n Enter the First String : ");
    fgets(string1, length, stdin);

    printf("\n The First String : %s ",string1);

    free(string1);      

    return 0;
}
```

Can someone help me on the above code ? I trying to get the length of a string and the string as inputs. But, I am able to enter only Length of the string. After that it skips the string input part.

This is the output I am getting :

```
sh-4.3$ main
10

Enter the First String :
The First String :
sh-4.3$
```

Comment: Did you type `10<enter>`? `fgets` will read this `<enter>`.

Comment: Yeah, this is what is happening. Use `scanf` instead of `fgets`.

Comment: Add a `getchar();` after the scanf to discard the new line character you left behind in stdin.

Comment: @Lundin the required library for malloc is `<stdlib.h>`, not `<stdint.h>`.

Comment: -> Scanf() won't consider whitespace. Hence I used fgets().
-> after getting input, I did press enter. 
-> I want to follow Standard C. 
-> Thanks for the stdlib.h suggestion/correction.

Comment: @Lundin : Thanks for getchar() suggestion. It worked. So is there a way to skip this new line character ?

Comment: @k.saravind See [The C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/stdio/gets_flush2.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- After typing `"10<enter>"` the `<enter>` or `"\n"` will remain in the
  stdin buffer, so you have to use `getchar()` after the `scanf` to
  remove it.
- Also you should `#include <stdlib.h>` instead of malloc.h.
- You `malloc` 1 character too less, because of the 0-terminator.
  `string1 = malloc(length + 1);` will do the job, the cast is not
  necessary and `sizeof(char)` is always 1.

Comment: Added a getchar() after scanf(). It worked. Thanks To all for taking time to help.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use `stdin` for string input you can use `fgetln`. I edited you example and now it looks like that:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char *string1;
    size_t length;

    //scanf("%d", &length);

    //string1 = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * length);


    printf("\n Enter the First String : ");
    //fgets(string1, length, stdin);
    string1 = fgetln(stdin, &length);
    string1[length] = '\0';

    printf("\n The First String : %s ",string1);

    free(string1);

    return 0;
}
```

Note: fgetln returns not a C string, you should add a NULL character to the end.

Comment: `fgetln` isn't standard. Use `fgets` instead.

Comment: Author of the question did not wrote nothing about the compiler. I used Apple LLVM.

Comment: Since it is tagged C with no mentioning of what system that's used, you should try to answer with standard C. Particularly, there is no reason to use non-standard functions that have standard equivalents.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple answer when reading from STDIN/keyboard with the newline etc.
is to just add the "\n" to the scanf, ie:

```
scanf("%d\n", &length);
```

Solves the problem ;)

PS: Beware of all the other security/buffer overflow issues of scanf